# Add strings from the off-topic close reasons manage page into transifex (or use existing keys)

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/flags/close-as-off-topic

> [image]

Some of those strings I couldn't find in the transifex at all. Some of them I found, but looks like on this page they are are not used. Could you add these strings into transifex or use existing strings?

Approximate list:

1. With great power comes great responsibility. Use sparingly and only in consultation with the community.
2. Manage Off-Topic Close Reasons
3. Default Off-Topic Close Reason
4. Shown when no 2 off-topic reasons match on a closed question.
5. edit
6. cancel
7. Save Edits
8. show deactivated
9. hide deactivated
10. reactivate
11. deactivate
12. Custom Off-Topic Close Reasons
13. active
14. Deactivated Custom Off-Topic Close Reasons
15. Add Custom Reason